# Send mail using my own SMTP Server

Tags: iis, smtp

I have windows server 2019 configured in AWS . Installed SMTP server role.

Now , i have a simple mail client which i downloaded from below github link.

https://github.com/CodeCowboyOrg/SimpleSMTPClient.

[Image shows that mail sent sucessfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nElu1.png)

The sender and receiver mail ID is my personal gmail account. I am not receiving this mail in my gmail inbox.

Any suggestion why i am not receiving mail ?

I think my understanding about smtp work flow is not good.

Please help me to understand.

Comment: What does the mail log on your AWS SMTP server tell you?  If it shoes gmail as accepting the message, have you checked if gmail has classified it as spam?

Comment: i didn't receive this in SPAM folder also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex subject not conducive to a single StackExchange post. Please do further research before asking a specific question. There is *much* more to do to have your mail accepted by commercial servers, especially Gmail and even then they are notoriously opaque about their criteria for spam.